# Pytorch Data Loader concatenate an image to input images

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch

In PyTorch data loader, how could I concatenate an image (let's say x.jpg) in-band wise to each and every input images. ie, in effect I will have 4 band input ( 3 band input jpg with 1 band x.jpg. How to implement it.

Please find below example of my current dataloader just to load the images. To this, I want to add x.jpg to "image"(ie input image, not to mask)

```
from PIL import Image

class lakeDataSet(Dataset):
   def __init__(self, root, transform):
   super().__init__()
   self.root = root
   self.img_dir = os.path.join(root,'image-c3/c3-crop')   #9UAV
   self.mask_dir = os.path.join(root,'label-c3/c3-crop')
   # self.mask_dir = os.path.join(root,'test')
   self.files = [fname for fname in os.listdir(self.img_dir) if fname.endswith('.jpg')]
self.transform = transform

   def __len__(self):
     return len(self.files)

   def __getitem__(self,I):
     fname = self.files[i]
     img_path = os.path.join(self.img_dir, fname)
     mask_path = os.path.join(self.mask_dir, fname)

     img = self.transform(Image.open(img_path))
     mask = self.transform(Image.open(mask_path))
     return img, mask
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Something like [`torch.tile`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tile.html) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the `self.transform` already has `ToTensor`. Otherwise you should specify it as well.

Then you can just concat the first dimension. Like

```
x_jpg = self.transform(Image.open('x.jpg'))
img = torch.cat((img, x_jpg), 0)
```

The `x.jpg` has to have only 1 channel, if it's an RGB then obviously it'll become 6 channels instead of 4.